# Installing PHPMyAdmin 4.x

Tags: 13.04, phpmyadmin

I am writing on behalf of a friend. He wants to know how to install PHPMyAdmin 4.x on Ubuntu 13.04. He already installed the `phpmyadmin` package but this one is the 3.5.8 version. So how would he go about downloading and updating the installed version to PHPMyAdmin 4.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I thought it would be harder to test this out. It turns out, installing the `phpmyadmin` package gives you an easy to use "Dash" icon.

[image]

So with that much appreciated help I could test this out quickly.

What I did was the following:

1. Download PHPMyAdmin from their site: http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php
2. Assuming you have already installed the `phpmyadmin` package, download the package you need from the sire. In my case I downloaded the **phpMyAdmin-4.0.0-english.7z** package from the official site and decompressed it in my Desktop folder. I then ran the following command in the terminal:

   ```
   sudo nautilus
   ```
3. After Nautilus opened, I proceeded to grab the content of the PHPMyAdmin folder in my desktop and pasted everything in `/usr/share/phpmyadmin`, overwriting anything it needed to overwrite. In my case, `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` is where the package phpmyadmin installed by default most of the files. I used the `sudo` command because I needed permissions to paste files in `usr/share`.
4. After opening phpmyadmin through the Dash, I was presented with the following:

[image]